# T-SQL Group/combine records

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql, group-by

I've got an activity table and it contains 'start' and (among many other) 'end' events.

```
person, datetime, event
1, 2015-01-1 13:30, start
2, 2015-01-1 13:33, start
3, 2015-01-1 13:38, start
2, 2015-01-1 13:57, end
1, 2015-01-1 14:03, end
1, 2015-01-1 14:07, start
1, 2015-01-1 14:12, end
```

And I wish to retrieve them something like this:

```
person, start, end
1, 2015-01-01 13:30, 2015-01-01 14:03
1, 2015-01-01 14:07, 2015-01-01 14:12
2, 2015-01-01 13:33, 2015-01-01 13:57
3, 2015-01-01 13:38, null
```

I can't seem to get the keywords together to find this kind of "combine rows by" mechanic or similar scenario.

Comment: What data type are the times?

Comment: What database are you working on mysql or SQL Server?

Comment: Sorry I've figured it out, it's was a simple sub query top 1, I've created the example in T-SQL but it also works in MySQL with minor modifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without a subquery

```
SELECT startevent.person_id as person, 
       startevent.datetime as [start],
       min(endevent.datetime) as [end]
  FROM person_events as startevent 
  join person_events as endevent 
    on startevent.person_id = endevent.person_id 
   and startevent.event = 'start'
   and endevent.event =   'end'
   and startevent.datetime < endevent.datetime
 GROUP BY startevent.person_id, startevent.datetime
 ORDER BY startevent.person_id, startevent.datetime
```

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me, the solution was incredibly simple.. I was overcomplicating things!

```
SELECT
    startevent.person_id as person,
    startevent.datetime as [start],
    (
        SELECT TOP 1
            endevent.datetime as [end]
        FROM
            person_events as endevent
        WHERE
            endevent.event = 'end'
        AND
            endevent.datetime >= startevent.datetime
        ORDER BY
            endevent.person_id,
            endevent.datetime
    ) as [end]
FROM
    person_events as startevent
WHERE
    event = 'start'
ORDER BY
    startevent.person_id,
    startevent.datetime
```